# How to find the difference between two python files and write output with file source information

Tags: python, file, set, symmetric-difference

I have been trying to compare two python files for differences in them.

**file_a.py**

```
some_var=<a line of code>
    # a coment
x  = some_var
```

**file_b.py**

```
ssome_var=<a line of code>
# a comment
x  = some_var
```

Now I want to do something like this:

Extract the lines from both files that *do not have an instance in either of them* and save the result to a 3rd file, and while writing the 3rd file, assign the source of the extracted line (i.e. the file name).

This is what I have tried which is generating an output file with the correct set of lines which do not have an instance in either of them, but I am unable to kind of put an **address* to those line/s.

```
f1='file_a.py'
f2='file_b.py'

with open(f1, 'r') as file1:
    with open(f2, 'r') as file2:
        diff = set(file1).symmetric_difference(file2)
        # Ascribe each item found to its respective source file
        result = dict([(i, ('f1' if i in file1 else 'f2')) for i in diff])

with open('comp_diff.py', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in result:
        file_out.write(line)
```

**Output file `comp_diff.py**

```
# a comment
some_var=<a line of code>
    # a coment
ssome_var=<a line of code>
```

Is there a way I can assign the `addresses` from where the lines were extracted from?

*PS*. Another point here. If I take a print of the var "result" in the output (in py shell) I get something like:

```
{'# a comment\n': 'f2', 'some_var=<a line of code>\n': 'f2', '    # a coment\n': 'f2', 'ssome_var=<a line of code>\n': 'f2'}
```

That is, all the values are marked **as from the file f2**!

Comment: "but I am unable to kind of put an *address to those line/s." - **What does this mean?** Please make sure you have a clear, unambiguous **specification** for the problem before trying to ask a how-to question. You should be able to show **exactly** what `comp_diff.py` **should** contain instead, and be able to state precise rules that can be generalized, so that we can clearly agree on whether a given attempt is giving the correct answer for a given test input.

Comment: Not to worry... **solved it!**